# Local offline Linux application similar to supergenpass?

Tags: passwords, password-management

I would like to store my passwords locally in a way similar to what [Supergenpass](http://supergenpass.com/) does: using a master password mix a domain name `example.com` with a username `exampleuser` and generate a unique password for each domain/username pair.

(As for now Supergenpass does not take username into account).

Does something like that exist for Linux platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SuperGenPass works just fine under Linux. All that's required is a Javascript-capable browser.

Alternatively, you can make your own. All SuperGenPass does is return the MD5 hash for the domain+master password, cut to the specified length. You can do basically the same thing from most shells:

```
user@example:~$ echo "helloworld123"|md5sum|cut -c -10
```

Comment: Yes, but it generates passwords from domain name. What if I need to store a password from a door lock? Supergenpass is a nice tool, but it is only for website-one-user usage.

Comment: All SuperGenPass does is return the MD5 hash for the domain+master password, cut to the specified length. You can do basically the same thing from most shells: `user@example:~$ echo "helloworld123"|md5sum|cut -c -10`

Comment: Also, you can manually specify the "domain" that SuperGenPass uses by open the Regenerate Password link and entering whatever you want for the domain.

Comment: Thanks for the shell example! Does 'echo "helloworld123"|md5sum|cut -c -10' generate exactly the same result on any shell and any machine?

Comment: Provided the input, "helloworld123" is exactly the same, then the output will be the same too, always.

Comment: Amazed, could you please post your comment about the shell thing as an answer?

Comment: @Martin Lee: Done.